# Function parameter validation in Powershell

Tags: powershell, validation, parameters, casting

Why does a [string] casted parameter with the 'value' $null in this example never throw an error (empty or $null), but a string with the value '$null' always throws? I would expect if passing a mandatory parameter, it is checked for $null/emptyness and thus an error is always thrown in these cases:

```
Function test_M_NoE ( [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] [string] $x ) {}

# test cases. Uncomment one:
[string]$x = [string]$null 
# $x = [string]$null
# [string]$x = $null
# $x = $null 

"1:"; test_M_NoE [string]$x # never error
"2:"; test_M_NoE $x         # always error
```

Comment: Converting `$null` to `[string]` in PowerShell results in an empty string (eg. `""` or `[String]::Empty`), so the argument passed is never actually `$null` once you cast to `[string]`. But in your case, `[string]$x` is not an actual cast expression - it's parsed in argument mode, and interpreted as an expandable string, eg. no different that `test_M_NoE "[string]$x"`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Ok, but an empty string should also throw (ValidateNotNullOrEmpty) and it always does in the last statement. Why not if I cast the parameter?

Comment: The expression `"[string]$null"` results in a non-empty string

Comment: $x = [string]$null; test_M_NoE $x yields an error. What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this works:

```
test_M_NoE [string]$x
```

Is that `[string]$x` is *not* being interpreted the way you expect.

Let's change your test function definition to help us better see what's actually going on:

```
function test_M_NoE {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$x
  )

  Write-Host "Argument value passed was: '$x'"
}
```

Now, let's try again:

```
PS ~> $x = $null
PS ~> test_M_NoE [string]$x
Argument value passed was: '[string]'
```

Aha! The argument expression `[string]$x` did *not* result in an empty string - it resulted in the literal string value `[string]`.

This is due to the fact that PowerShell attempts to parse command arguments differently from anything else. From the [`about_Parsing` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing):

> Argument mode is designed for parsing arguments and parameters for commands in a shell environment. **All input is treated as an expandable string** unless it uses one of the following syntaxes: [...]

So really, PowerShell interprets our argument expression like a double-quoted string:

```
test_M_NoE "[string]$x"
```

At which point the behavior makes sense - `$x` is `$null`, so it evaluates to an empty string, and the result of the expression `"[string]$x"` is therefore just `[string]`.

Enclose the argument expression in the `$(...)` subexpression operator to have it evaluated as a value expression instead of as an expandable string:

```
test_M_NoE $([string]$x)
```

Comment: That makes sense now, thank you. To me very unexpected though. So as a consequence I suppose one should not cast function parameters at all and always make sure the parameter already has got the correct type, true?

Comment: @jamacoe no, not at all. My recommendation would be: *don't do anything* - PowerShell will automatically attempt to convert/coerce the argument to the target type, so your attempts at manually converting the argument to `[string]` explicitly is completely unnecessary.